# How to share pass via email

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

I created a pass and can add it via app or web server in MAMP. What about sharing via email , how can I share it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Mail.app, now I can send a pass to others to add to passbook !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.  Note that the MIME type needs to be `application/vnd.apple.pkpass` in order for the device to recognise it as a Passbook pass.

```
$pass = "pass.pkpass";
$path = "/path/to/pass/";
$from_name = "smallgirl";
$from_mail = "smallgirl@smallgirl.co.kr";
$reply_to = "smallgirl@smallgirl.co.kr";
$subject = "Your Passbook Pass.";
$message = "Hello,\r\nHere's your pass.";

email_pass($pass, $path, "recipient@mail.org", 
           $from_mail, $from_name, $reply_to, $subject, $message);

function email_pass($pass, $path, $mail_to, $from_mail, $from_name, $reply_to, $subject, $message) {
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path.$pass)));
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $name = basename($pass);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass; name=\"".$pass."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$pass."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";
    if (mail($mail_to, $subject, "", $header)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I not really understand ! Do I have to create a php file with theses code above and then share it via email ?

Comment: This code will allow your server to email the file - the best place to add it would be in the php file that you are using to create the pass.  If you just want to email the file manually then just attach the .pkpass file to any email like you would any other file!

Comment: If I attach .pkpass, it just a file , not a pass and user also cannot add to passbook !

Comment: I try already, but it doesn't work . Here is the code :                 <?php   
header("Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass; charset=UTF-8");
$pass = "DigiClubCard.pkpass";
$path = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/'; 
$from_name = "Malin";
$from_mail = "malinchhan@gmail.com";
$reply_to = "Malin";
$subject = "Pass";
$message = "Hello,\r\nHere's your pass.";

Comment: email_pass($pass, $path, "malinchhan@gmail.com", 
           $from_mail, $from_name, $reply_to, $subject, $message);
...............

Comment: You don't need this line - `header("Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass; charset=UTF-8");` "It doesn't work" doesn't help much, can explain precisely what is not working - and also check your PHP logs to see if there are any errors in your code.  What mail client are you using when you attach the pass?  If the .pkpass bundle is valid, Mac Mail should recognise it as a pass.

Comment: Could you tell me how to test it?

Comment: Visit the URL of this file in your browser, then check your PHP logs which, according to the [MAMP documentation](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/mamp/faq/where-can-i-find-the-logs/where-can-i-find-the-php-error-log) should be in `/Applications/MAMP/logs/php_error.log`

Comment: nothing happens when I visit this URL even I edit error that I see in php_error.log !

Comment: Nothing should happen in the browser at least - there a re a whole host of reasons why you may not be able to send the email (e.g. firewall, your ISP blocking mail ports, etc.).  Sorry but I don't understand your second point. What is in the error log?

Comment: Also, you might want to delete your comments that contains your personal email

Comment: This is error i get: [28-Mar-2013 09:53:55 Europe/Berlin] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/emailAPass.php on line 39

Comment: do i visit url on device or mac ?

Comment: Visit on either - then look again in your logs because there may be other errors.